# Simple RSS with PHP?

Tags: php, rss, dynamically-generated

How do I make a completely simple, static, RSS feed using PHP?

Why would this not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version=\"2.0\">
<channel>

<?php echo "<title>The Channel Title Goes Here</title>"; ?>
<description>The explanation of how the items are related goes here</description>
<link>http://www.directoryoflinksgohere</link>

<item>
<title>The Title Goes Here</title>
<description>The description goes here</description>
<link>http://www.linkgoeshere.com</link>
</item>

<item>
<title>Another Title Goes Here</title>
<description>Another description goes here</description>
<link>http://www.anotherlinkgoeshere.com</link>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

I will of course need to make this automatically updated with mysql, but right now I just need to know how the heck I can even use php in conjunction with RSS.

This actually causes the RSS file to download rather than display:

```
<?php

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>

<title>The Channel Title Goes Here</title>
<description>The explanation of how the items are related goes here</description>
<link>http://www.directoryoflinksgohere</link>

<item>
<title>The Title Goes Here</title>
<description>The description goes here</description>
<link>http://www.linkgoeshere.com</link>
</item>

<item>
<title>Another Title Goes Here</title>
<description>Another description goes here</description>
<link>http://www.anotherlinkgoeshere.com</link>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>";

?>
```

UPDATE:

This will output the RSS correctly. Almost. The value of the variables are not written but rather the name of the variable e.g. it will write "$toast" rather than writing "YES".

```
<?php

$counter = 0;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM people");


while($row = mysqli_ffetch_array($sql)){
$test[$counter] = $row['name'];
$counter++;
}

$toast = "YES";


echo "

header(\"Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1\")

<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>

<title>The Channel Title Goes Here</title>
<description>$test[0]</description>
<link>http://www.directoryoflinksgohere</link>

<item>
<title>The Title Goes Here</title>
<description>$toast</description>
<link>http://www.linkgoeshere.com</link>
</item>

<item>
<title>Another Title Goes Here</title>
<description>Another description goes here</description>
<link>http://www.anotherlinkgoeshere.com</link>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>";

?>
```

Comment: No matter what I do (various tests from other site) Firefox keeps trying to download the RSS file rather than execute it when ever I use PHP to output the content. Really frustrating that something supposedly simple is so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Add a .htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemaps.xml$ /sitemap.php [L]
```

Create sitemap.php with the code you had posted

**Done**

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track. One of the important things to do will be to set the correct headers to indicate the content type (application/rss+xml).  Furthermore, the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` tag will cause issues with PHP, so it's easier to `echo` that.  Such as, `<?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"; ?>`.

Comment: When I try to echo everything the files begins to download. See updated question.

Comment: The first part of this, the content type header, should fix this. IE, `header('Content-type: application/rss+xml')`

Comment: Thank you that helped with the basic output, but for some reason I can not get any variable to work. Rather than outputting the value of the variable it will write the name of the variable instead.

Comment: A couple typos. First, `mysql_ffetch_array` should be `mysql_fetch_array`.  And `header` is a function. Is should be called before any output.